# How to display form loading state in NextJs Server Action

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have been strugling to find how to get loading state in NextJs Server Action. Im aware that there is solution using client component and routes api. But in this case Im using react server action. NextJs 13/14 doesnt allow react hooks on server component to get the loading state. Below, is the code I want to get the form loading state to make loading UI in submit button.

/page.tsx

```js
export default async function Page() {
  const signUp = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";

    const email = formData.get("email") as string;
    const password = formData.get("password") as string;
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);

    return redirect("/dashboard");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      sign up form
      <form action={signUp}>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a pending state while a form is submitting, you can call the `useFormStatus` Hook inside a button component rendered inside a `<form>`, you can see the  [React Rocs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormStatus) or in the [Nextjs Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#displaying-loading-state). There is also `useFormState` hooks for managing form state in React Server Action.

SubmitButton.tsx

```js
"use client";

import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

export default function SubmitButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return <button type="submit">{pending ? "loading..." : "Submit"}</button>;
}
```

Comment: The question post is asking in a context of server side rendering ("use server"), your answer example is in the context of client side only ("use client"), therefore in server rendering he can't use any hooks, I suggest you check twice the question before aswer.